# Passando propriedades por eventos

Tags: vue.js

Eu tenho um componente em que nele está apenas uma modal que tem o seguinte cabeçalho:

```
<b-modal id="mdgroup"  ref="mdgroup" size="lg" title="Nova categoria de receita"  @ok="save" ok-title="Salvar" cancel-title="Cancelar">
```

No componente pai, onde essa modal fica eu gostaria de chamar ela ao clicar em uma especie de botão:

```
<a href="#" v-on:click="showModal()"><icon name="eye" scale="1.6"></icon></a>
```

Eu consigo chamar ela de boa, da seguinte forma:

```
showModal(){
    this.$root.$emit('bv::show::modal','mdgroup')
}
```

Mas a dúvida é, como eu posso passar algum valor como propriedade para essa modal? Existe outra forma de chamar ela sem ter que emitir evento?

Comment: Se o modal for um componente que está dentro desse componente use `props` a sua finalidade é para isso, o `emit` é para notificar o componente pai que um evento ocorreu no componente filho.

Comment: Ta, mas como eu chamaria esse componente ao clicar no botão?

Comment: Por exemplo, supondo que você tenha um componente com os detalhes do pedido. Você poderia passar uma variável booleana para esse componente, isso faria o controle de abertura e fechamento do modal, exemplo `<detalhes-pedido
      :opened="opened"
    />` **(isso vai no componente pai)**. Quando você clicar em um botão que deve abrir o modal é só trocar essa variável de `false` para `true`. No componente filho você deve receber essa variável com um props assim: `props: ['opened'],`

Answer (score 0):

Suponho que você esteja usando a biblioteca bootstrap-vue.

O componente em questão (`b-modal`) expõe os métodos de `hide` e `show` veja o exemplo na documentação oficial: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/modal/

o segredo está em

```html
<b-modal ref="my-modal" />
```

a diretiva `ref` é do próprio Vue, você pode aprender mais sobre ela aqui: https://br.vuejs.org/v2/api/index.html#ref

e no js você pode acessar a instancia do componente dessa maneira

```js
showModal() {
   this.$refs['my-modal'].show()
},
```